# $\text{tr}(X)=\text{tr}(A^{-1}B)$ for $AX+XA=2B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose X is a solution to following equation over positive definite matrices $A$,$B$

$$XA+AX=2B$$

The following seems to hold ([numerically](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-lyapunov-trace.nb))

$$\text{tr}(X)=\text{tr}(A^{-1} B)$$

Can anyone see the way to prove this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive definite, it has an inverse. Hence
$$ +=2 \\ \Rightarrow 
A^{-1}XA +X=2A^{-1}B.$$
Taking $Tr(\cdot)$ on both sides leads to
$$Tr(A^{-1}XA) + Tr(X) = 2Tr(A^{-1}B)\\
\Rightarrow Tr(AA^{-1}X) + Tr(X) = 2Tr(A^{-1}B)\\
\Rightarrow Tr(X) + Tr(X) = 2Tr(A^{-1}B) \\
\Rightarrow  Tr(X) = Tr(A^{-1}B) $$

The second line above is due to the rotation property of the $Tr(\cdot)$ operation.

Answer (score 3):

$XA+AX=2B$

$A^{-1}XA+A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}2B=2A^{-1}B$

$\text{tr}(A^{-1}XA)+\text{tr}(A^{-1}AX)=\text{tr}(A^{-1}2B)=2\text{tr}(A^{-1}B)$

Since $\text{tr}(A^{-1}XA) = \text{tr}(X) $

We get $\text{tr}(X)=\text{tr}(A^{-1} B)$